# start a service automatically when rails server start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to start a service automatically when rails server start, how should I go for that.
Where I have to specify that.
below is the command I want to run automatically when server starts

```
service proftpd start
```

Comment: you can use foreman https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Comment: @usmanali - thanks for the suggestion. But I don't want to use any gem

Answer (score 3):

You can use [initialization events](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events), in `config/application.rb` add:

```
config.before_initialize do
  system('sh test.sh')
end
```

in Rails root dir create a file `test.sh` with command what you need. In my case it is just shell `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

When run server.

```
 $> bundle exec rails server
 => Booting Puma
 => Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using  127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the such a lightening reply, let me try this if this works for me

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I put `service proftpd restart` in `test.sh`. and `reboot` the server, still it's not working. I don't know what I had done wrong

Comment: this is worked example, i am pretty sure that problem in your current command or permissions. What kind of errors you have?

Comment: I am not using `bundle exec rails server`, I am using `reboot` command

Comment: initialization events works only when your restart your rails server, i dosent what `reboot` do.

Comment: I don't have `application.rb` file in config,  I have added code in `environment.rb` and `/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: `application.rb` it is a main configuration file in any rails app and rails app can't work without it. All of this very good described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: I am using `rails 2.3.18` does that make any difference?

Comment: @Sontya yes. It is works only after 3.12 i think. and tag on your question talk about 4 version

Comment: my bad, changed it. Can you tell me according to rails 2

Comment: sorry, but i do not work with old rails versions, only >= 3.12